# How to deploy webapp or war file in tomcat that is running in docker container

Tags: docker

I have created Docker container and Tomcat is running in this container. How can I deploy a webapp or war file in Tomcat that is running in docker container.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Docker add warfile to official Tomcat image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818856/docker-add-warfile-to-official-tomcat-image)

Answer (score 4):

First create a Dockerfile:

```
FROM library/tomcat
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*
ADD ./relative/path_to_war.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
```

Then build Docker image

```
$ docker build -t user/image_name .
```

And finally run docker container.

```
$ docker run --name container_name -p 80:8080 -d user/image_name
```

After that your webapp should be responding on Docker host's ip on default http 80 port.

You might need to link a database container to your webapp, see more on [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/)

Answer (score 3):

You can implement an effective way of using Tomcat Docker.

```
docker run -d -p 80:8080 -v <mount-path>:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ tomcat:8.0
```

And then copy the .war files to the mounted volume. This would eliminate the need for restarting the Tomcat Docker each time when there is a code change. A zero downtime implementation could be achieved.

If it's a one-time deployment then you may create a custom Docker and copy the war file into `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/` and start the Docker.