# Tomcat & Docker - How to execute a shell script after running catalina.sh?

Tags: docker, tomcat, docker-compose, sed, tomcat8

##### Background:

I am trying to run a website powered by Tomcat and Docker. However, I need to replace a line in the `database.properties` file in order to connect to a MySQL container.

---

##### What I have done :

`docker-compose.yaml` :

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  tomcat-web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 8800:8080
```

`Dockerfile.dev` :

```
FROM tomcat:8.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat

# Copy a shell script and make it executable
COPY --chmod=0755 startup.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh

# Clean '/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/' in order to allow tomcat to expand web.war 
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*

COPY target/web.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["sh", "/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh"]
```

Removing everything in `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*` was advised by https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095790/14418391.

`startup.sh` (to change a line in `database.properties` and run catalina.sh) :

```bash
# Changing port (from port 3306 to port 3311) in database.properties 
DB_CONFIG_FILE=/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/database.properties
MYSQL_CONTAINER_PORT=3311

sed -i 's~^database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database_name.*database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3311/database_name~' $DB_CONFIG_FILE

sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

`database.properties` :

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database_name
```

---

##### The Problem :

The docker container of the website successfully ran, but I found `database.properties` **remained untouched**.

---

##### Expectation & Question :

`database.properties` (Modification of port to 3311) :

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3311/database_name
```

However, to accomplish that, should I run catalina.sh before the `sed` command, **in order to allow catalina.sh to expand ROOT.WAR**, like following?

```bash
sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run

# Changing port (from port 3306 to port 3311) in database.properties 
DB_CONFIG_FILE=/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/database.properties
MYSQL_CONTAINER_PORT=3311

sed -i 's~^database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database_name.*database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3311/database_name~' $DB_CONFIG_FILE
```

Thank you, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can load your own .properties inside your .war like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281512/how-to-read-data-from-java-properties-file-using-spring-boot . Why your web server needs to know about the database of  one site / application?

Comment: @Mate Well, ideally I would like to get database properties from a file that stores environment variables, just like a `.env` file in a common NodeJS application. However, it is a legacy project..

Answer (score 0):

To be able to change the `database.url` in the database.properties, change it from :

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database_name
```

to

```
database.url=jdbc:mysql://%%MYSQL_HOST%%/database_name
```

Meanwhile, minor changes have been introduced in `Dockerfile.dev` :

```
FROM tomcat:9.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat

RUN apk update && apk add \ 
  zip \
  sed

# Add web.war and extract it under a tomcat directory
ADD sources/ship-web/target/web.war /tmp/ROOT.war
RUN unzip -o /tmp/ROOT.war -d /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT

# Copy application configurations
COPY ./docker/config /usr/local/tomcat/config-templates

# Copy the startup script and make it executable
COPY --chmod=0755 startup.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["sh", "/usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh"]
```

In `docker-compose.yaml`, environment variables were included :

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  tomcat-web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    env_file:
      - db.env
    ports:
      - 8800:8080
```

This is what inside of `db.env` is :

```
MYSQL_HOST=mysql
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

The value of `MYSQL_HOST` depends on mysql service name, which is defined in the docker-compose.yaml.

The startup script is responsible for changing the `database.url` :

```bash
#!/bin/sh

dbConfigTemplate=/usr/local/tomcat/config-templates/database.properties
dbConfigFile=/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/database.properties

cp $dbConfigTemplate $dbConfigFile

sed -i "s/%%MYSQL_HOST%%/$MYSQL_HOST:$MYSQL_PORT/g" $dbConfigFile

sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```