# Run war with tomcat in docker

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

I've followed these two post [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201262/deploying-java-webapp-to-tomcat-8-running-in-docker-container) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818856/docker-add-warfile-to-official-tomcat-image) and neither work. I'm currently building my tomcat with the below.

Build File

```
FROM tomcat:8.0

COPY server/build/libs/server.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/server.war

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Terminal

```
docker build -t my_server .

docker run -it -rm -p 8080:8080
```

When I go to `http:localhost:8080` I see the manager home page but `http:localhost:8080/server` or `http:localhost:8080/server/webapp/`do not show up. My terminal tells me that my war is getting added, but nothing that says it's expanded

```
 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/server.war has finished in 2,518 ms
```

Comment: can you paste here your web.xml? this is where we can see the prefix of your endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

For removing the manager app, you need to put the following RUN command before you copy the WAR in DockerFile.

RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*

The above command removes the default apps available in tomcat.

Your application should be available at http:localhost:8080/server/