# What is the default webapp location on the tomcat8 docker container?

Tags: tomcat, docker, war

I'm trying to deploy a war file to the tomcat 8.5 docker container:

https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/

I have a Dockerfile I've created but I cannot figure out where to copy my war file

```
FROM tomcat:8.5
MAINTAINER nobody

RUN ["rm", "-rf", "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT"]  
RUN ["rm", "-rf", "/usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT"]

COPY companyNews.war /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/companyNews.war
COPY companyNews.war /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/companyNews.war
COPY companyNews.war /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/companyNews.war
COPY companyNews.war /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/companyNews.war

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]


EXPOSE 8080
```

Can someone show me where to copy my war file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker add warfile to official Tomcat image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818856/docker-add-warfile-to-official-tomcat-image). I think that answers your question. It's in the docs as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to copy your war file to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/`

```
FROM tomcat:8.5

ADD your.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Answer (score 0):

FROM tomcat:8.5

MAINTAINER anybody

COPY your.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/your.war

CMD chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

EXPOSE 8080

Comment: Hi @Kumaresh, since there's already a very similar answer to this question could you please add more detail to yours?