# deploy war file on tomcat docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to deploy my web app to tomcat which running on docker. I have a directory "test" and it has two files:

-docker.compose.yml

-sample.war
(I download it from here `https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/`)

Here is my docker-compose.yml content:

```
  my-test:
    image: tomcat
    ports:
       - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
       - ./hello.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/hello.war
```

I am running `docker-compose up` in "test" directory.

Then I am taking this :  `http://paste.ubuntu.com/23108774/`

`docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED                 STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
49bf16c1f366        tomcat              "catalina.sh run"   12 minutes     ago      Up 17 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   test_my-test_1
```

I am going to `localhost:8080` then I see only Tomcat Home page.

But when I go `localhost:8080/sample`

```
HTTP Status 404 - /sample

type Status report

message /sample

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
```

I didnt understand why my web app is not running on localhost:8080/sample. where I am wrong?

docker version :1.12.1
OS:ubuntu 16.04

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818856/docker-add-warfile-to-official-tomcat-image

Answer (score 0):

You mount a wrong volume:

```
- ./hello.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/hello.war
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be available at `hello` not `sample` ?

Comment: rename hello.war to sample.war and try again. it's not about docker, I think it's about tomcat context.